# Mega 2560 problem again. Please help!

Tags: arduino

I have a problem again with an Arduino Mega 2560 board (SainSmart). The IDE gets stuck at the "Uploading to I/O board..." message. The bargraph shows around 95% but then there is no further progress. I tried this with Windows 7 64bit and Win XP, with 101 and 0023. Uploading is impossible. Board type and COM port are correctly set in the IDE. Any ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: Is there any error message or does it just hang? If it hangs does it have an info bar saying at what stage?

Comment: Did you try verbose mode? Turn on verbose mode in preferences(1.0) or hold shift(0022)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another Mega board to test with? That way we can tell if it's just this specific board. Is it timing out? Something like...

```
avrdude: stk500_2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
```

It could very well be a driver issue. Give this a go:

> **Mac:**
>
> 1) Go to System Preferences -> Network
>
> 2) If it asks you to add the Arduino (modem device), say cancel
>
> 3) Remove the Arduino device from the list if its there
>
> 4) Try uploading a sketch!
>
> **PC:**
>
> 1) Go to Device Manager
>
> 2) Find your Arduino in the list, go to its properties and update its driver manually, using the .inf file which came with your Arduino (0021+) IDE

Also, make sure you're not sending `!!!` via serial at any point in your sketch as that initiates a special monitoring mode baked into the bootloader.

[Source](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,28656.0.html)

Also, take a look at the [official Arduino troubleshooting guide](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/troubleshooting#toc1).